# spl autoload function returns error on server

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

Hello guys i am trying to use the spl autoload function it works perfectly on my local server but it returns an error when i am online. i tink its server problems but i'll need someone to steer me which way to look i have the code below

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
require_once 'classes/'. $class .'.php';
}
);
```

and the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in
>   /home/www/ftwrkdesign.com on line 22

NB: classes is a folder and absolute path to it returned same error php server version is 5.5.29

Comment: _php server version is 5.5.29_ I would check again, from the error it looks like you have <5.3 installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you `php` version supports `anonymous functions` , they come only from `php 5.3` . If your version is below `5.3` you should define your function before passing it to `spl_autoload_register()` .

```
<?php
    function qwerty($class){
        require_once 'classes/'. $class .'.php';
    }
    spl_autoload_register('qwerty');
```

Comment: @user3005115 : run `php -v` in your terminal. Or add `phpinfo()` in your `index` file and go to `localhost` to see all information about your php.

Comment: @user3005115 : php on your server has version < 5.3. Define function and only after that pass it to the `spl_autoload_register()`. I've updated my post to show you how.

Comment: thanks i found out that the admin hadnt concluded the upgraded package that was paid for. thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP version on your server does not allow anonymous functions.

That's why the parser doesn't allow the function keyword after the opening parenthesis.